# Folders randomly dissapear in Eclipse's workspace

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently working in a Java project using Eclipse. One day my complete sprites folder saved in .../workspace/[project name]/bin/ randomly disappeared. I searched in my recycle bin, other folders, and even used a program to restored deleted files from my PC and there was no trace of the folder or missing files. I lost a lot of work and hours and got really really mad, so I learned that I had to save backups everywhere.
Some minutes ago I was working in my project again, I rebooted my computer and it happened again. I have backups, yes, but it's getting very annoying.

I don't know if it is right to ask this here but do you have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bin folder is output and might be cleared entirely if you do a Project->Clean.  **Never put things there directly.**

If you want something other than Java sources to be copied over with your generated class files, just put them under a source folder.

Comment: Inside my project's folder in workspace I have a folder named "bin" and another named "src". Can I put, for example, another folder named "sprites" inside src and place all my .png there?

Comment: I tried to do it, but it doesn't work if I put them inside src. Only works if I use bin folder...

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you letting it build after putting it in src?